# Something's a bit off about this

Tags: cipher, steganography

<< I received an email today, but I'm not sure how I'm meant to read it. The body of the message just contained `®ÞîX@èÐÂè@îÂæ@æêäÊ@Â@ÄÒè@ÞÌÌX@îÂæÜNè@Òè~`. Something about it just seemed a bit off. The more I looked at it the more off it seemed. I'm not sure what it's trying to tell me. >>

Comment: I know what you are hinting at with this puzzle, but I tried the same thing in you-know-where and it didn’t bring up anything meaningful. Is there more to it than just this?

Comment: @tyobrien The accepted answer does it, which direction are you trying?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It says

> Wow, that was sure a bit off, wasn't it?

and it is a bit off in the sense that

> all its bytes have been shifted left by one bit.